# YAML to DB CRUD with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, yaml, php-mongodb

I want to have a simple form with PHP that takes YAML code as an input and stores it in to MongoDB when submitted. The update of records should also happen in the same way with editing yaml codes.

I am a beginner in programming and I don't want to use a framework or any complicated stuff just simple php form that takes yaml and converts to mongodb to be stored. 
How should I do that?

Any recommendations or sample codes or if you know previous similar work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [YAML Symfony component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) to load and parse the YAML file. The result of parsing the file will be a PHP array. This array can be easily saved into MongoDB:

1. [Download Composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/)

   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin
2. Use composer to install the YAML Component. Create a composer.json file and add the following information:

   {
   "require": {
   "symfony/yaml": "2.3.*@dev"
   }
   }
3. [Install the component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html)

   $ php composer.phar install
4. Create a php file with the code to load from the YAML file and save the result to the db. Part of the following code was taken from the [php.net mongodb tutorial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) :

   yaml;

    // select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
    $collection = $db->imports;

    // add a record
    $document = $yaml;
    $collection->insert($document);

    // find everything in the collection
    $cursor = $collection->find();

    echo "

   ```
   ";

    // iterate through the results
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        print_r($document);
    }

    echo "
   ```

   ";

Check out the data in MongoDB :

```
> show dbs;
yaml    0.203125GB 
> use yaml;
switched to db yaml
> show collections;
imports
system.indexes
> db.imports.find();
```